# MVVMLight support for input validation (Silverlight)

Tags: mvvm-light

Is there any support in MVVMLight for input validation?

Thanks,

Juan Carlos Galvez

Comment: of course there is, but this question is not well formed.  What kind of validation, how do you want it displayed to the user, where should the logic be executed etc...  IF you put more thought in you are more likely to get a response.  Have you even googled and read up on possibilities?

Comment: @J King The same kind of validation I get when I use silverlight DataForm and DomainDataSource instead of MVVM, that is: I mark my model properties with attributes and then I get all properties validated one by one and also the model as a whole, I'm sure I won't get this kind of support with MVVM but what I was hoping to see is not having to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo on my ViewModels, that is, getting some kind of support from ViewModelBase. I've googled and all that I've seen is people having to implement their on ViewModel base class deriving from ViewModelBase and INotifyDataErrorInfo

Comment: @J King Also, if there is any kind of support for model validation on MVVMLight please tell me where.

Comment: @J King from google: http://www.basarat.com/2011/02/mvvmlight-extensions-part-mvvm.html --- this one is kind of old but this is what I read trhere: "The project focuses a lot on providing the minimum amount of built in functionality to give you the ability to make effective MVVM applications. This means that there are some areas (like validation) where MVVMLight does not add anything more that what is already available with WPF / Silverlight. So wanting to extend the library with your own extensions is a normal desire." As I said the post is old but is MVVMLight still like that?

Comment: Where or how is your model defined?  I personally have created a base validation class that I add to my model.  (My model is entity framework with sql back end)  I then use partial classes to extend the model and inherit my ValidationBase class.  This allows me to validate against properties individually for INotifyDataErrorInfo and then I Also implement IValidatableObject in the ValidationBase class that validates the model object as a whole before entity framework context operations(CRUD) are performed.  IS this what you are looking for?

Comment: So if you are asking if the MVVM light framework itself has any custom built functions for validation outside of WPF/silverlight, the answer is no.

Comment: @J King Yes, that was my question, please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as an answer. I endup changing my solution so now I bind directly to RIA entities,  they implement validation so I don't have to doit myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are asking if the MVVM light framework itself has any custom built functions for validation outside of WPF/silverlight, the answer is no.

Comment: Thought I would add how I pulled this off recently in case it helps someone. By default there is nothing but here is one approach. [MVVM Light and Model Validation](http://toadcode.blogspot.com/2013/12/mvvm-light-and-model-validation.html)